# parameters in MySQLi

Tags: php, parameters, mysqli

I'm using PHP with MySQLi, and I'm in a situation where I have queries like

```
SELECT $fields FROM $table WHERE $this=$that AND $this2=$that2
```

So far I've written some code that splices up an array that I give it, for example:

```
$search = array(name=michael, age=20) //turns into
SELECT $fields FROM $table WHERE name=michael AND age=20
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I'm rather worried about MySQL injections - this seems very vulnerable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Oddly enough, the title to your question is basically the answer to it. You want to do something like this, using mysqli parameterized queries:

```
$db = new mysqli(<database connection info here>);
$name = "michael";
$age = 20;

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT $fields FROm $table WHERE name = ? AND age = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $name, $age);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

More information in the [mysqli section of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), specifically the functions related to [MySQLi_STMT](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php).

Note that I personally prefer using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) over mysqli, I don't like all the `bind_param` / `bind_result`  stuff that mysqli does. If I have to use it I write a wrapper around it to make it work more like PDO.