# PHP MySQL Query Doesn't Insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having some issues trying to insert a query into the database.
I have this php form that should do an insert query but nothing happens, not even an error.

This is an example query with the form:

```
INSERT INTO FlashVideoList ('title', 'urltitle', 'description', 'tags', 'category', 'filename', 'filetype', 'size', 'uploadedbyuser', 'uploadtime') VALUES ('testtitle','testtitle','test','testtags','FlashVideo','SMILE!.swf','application/x-shockwave-flash','1007525','0','1339102426');
```

i echoed the contents of the query to get this

This is the php code:

```
function MySqlQuery($Query)
{
    // Invokes global connection info
    global $MySQL_Host, $MySQL_Username, $MySQL_Password, $MySQL_Database, $MySQL_Port;
    global $mysqli;

    // runs query
    $result = $mysqli->query($Query);
    return $result;
}

$mysqli = new mysqli($MySQL_Host, $MySQL_Username, $MySQL_Password, $MySQL_Database, $MySQL_Port);

    MySqlQuery("INSERT INTO FlashVideoList ('title', 'urltitle', 'description', 'tags', 'category', 'filename', 'filetype', 'size', 'uploadedbyuser', 'uploadtime') " .
    "VALUES ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['Title']) . "','" . $mysqli->real_escape_string(GetUrlTitle()) . "','" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['Description']) . "','" .
    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['Tags']) . "','" . $_SESSION['Category'] . "','" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($FlashFileName) . "','" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_FILES["file"]["type"]) . "','" .
    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_FILES["file"]["size"]) . "','" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($UploadUserID) . "','" . time() . "');");

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Any help is appereciated, thanks
Select queries work fine with this same code

EDIT: Alright, i've made some progress, it seems that about everything possible is wrong with this code :P so yeah this is my query now:

```
INSERT INTO FlashVideoList (`title`, `urltitle`, `description`, `tags`, `category`, `filename`, `filetype`, `size`, `uploadedbyuser`, `uploadtime`) VALUES (`letitle`,`letitle`,``,`tagzz`,`FlashVideo`,`585336_pokemonsnewgrounds.swf`,`application/x-shockwave-flash`,`5058231`,`0`,`1339103842`);
```

And if I run it directly through navicat i get the error:

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'letitle' in 'field list'
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong? :/

Comment: MySQL identifiers should be quoted using the backtick character ` not the apostrophe character '.

Comment: You are not doing any error checking so its no wonder it doesn't output an error even when there is one, isn't it? The manual on `mysqli_query()` shows how to check for errors: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Column names should be in backticks, not quotes

Comment: Can you run that INSERT query directly in the database and see whether it generates an error?

Comment: I see, sorry I'm pretty new to all this so, I'll try doing that

Comment: Using backticks should fix it, but make sure you *do* add some error handling nevertheless. One more thing, consider using parametrized queries, those will no longer require `real_escape_string`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728229/parameters-in-mysqli

Comment: It also helps to format the code so that it is readable. Newlines and spaces are very cheap and on special offer this week!

Comment: Alright, I updated the code some but it's still being difficult

Comment: Don't put backticks around the *values*!  Only around field names.

Comment: I've learned a whole lot here :P Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message. What error message? Well, that's another issue, but it would have said *why* the insert failed<sup>1</sup>.

One (but perhaps not the only) problem as mentioned in the comments is that `'` is not a valid identifier quote and thus results in a parse error. In MySQL the default is `` ` ``, but it can be changed (to `"`) if using [ANSI quotes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-sql-mode.html).

```
INSERT INTO FlashVideoList (`title`, ...)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [Here is an example of basic error handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for mysqli (scroll to the bottom). The basic idea is, if the `query` returns FALSE then something failed and `error` can/should be consulted.

Also, I'd recommend cleaning up the code and getting rid of the "proxy" function call.

Answer (score 1):

Use `msysqli_error()` to help find out the error

eg. `mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 0):

Why use backticks (or single quotes) in the first place? They let you use reserved words, but that's not something I'd propagate. Use sensible column names instead.