# Mysql insert query isn't working in php file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am new to php and trying to insert some values to my database table but query isn't working when I am passing values by php variables. The same query was working with static values.

I am making my database connection in init.php and the variable in there for same is $dbc.

```
<?php
require "init.php";

$mobile = "100004";
$email = "vikas4@web";
$password = "4444"

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, "INSERT INTO user_login (user_mobile, user_email, user_pwd) values(?, ?, ?)";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $mobile, $email, $password);
echo "after sql_query";

?>
```

For more detail, When I am replacing my $sql_query with below static code, it is inserting into database.

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_mobile, user_email, user_pwd) values('1000055', 'vikas55@web', '5555')";
```

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: If you echo `$sql_query` you will see that the query is invalid. The wrong way to solve this, is to add quotes around the values in the string. The right way is to use [prepared statements and passing the values are parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Query Doesn't Insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939819/php-mysql-query-doesnt-insert)

Comment: So your problem is solved?

Comment: I didn't echo $sql_query. It is simple string in last.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use quotes to insert string values

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_mobile, user_email, user_pwd) values('$mobile', '$email', '$password')";
```

But even this is not a good solution as you wqould be vulnerable to sql injections.

Use prepared statements to avoid these security issues:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, "INSERT INTO user_login (user_mobile, user_email, user_pwd) values(?, ?, ?)";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $mobile, $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Prepared statements will handle all the escaping and quote encapsulation necessary to be safe.

If you'd like to dig into the topic you may read nice tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: The quotes version is bad practice. Your other solution uses the object notation, while OP uses the functional libraries. This will be very confusing for a beginner.

Comment: I updated my main post with your code but not working till now. Could you please check and put the answer for query. @GolezTrol

Comment: Please add the `mysqli_stmt_execute()` from my example. It's needed to actually execute the sql statement.

Comment: Thanks all. Its working now. I used  prepared statements and passing the values are parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If user_mobile type defined int or other numeric types, you should not use '.
so you can test this:

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_mobile, user_email, user_pwd) values($mobile, '$email', '$password')";
```

Comment: It's very bad practise to do it like this. An answer similar to yours was already deleted. If you would do this, you would also have to escape quotes and other characters in the values. BTW, what you say about the numeric value is not true. You can use quotes around numeric values and MySQL will just convert it. Whether 'mobile' *should* be numeric at all is a completely different matter.