# MySQL "INSERT INTO"-error: which quotation do I have to use?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm making a search engine based on the API of Faroo.com (http://www.faroo.com/hp/api/api.html) for a school project. I would like to index the index of Faroo, so that users (in my situation, children) can vote up or vote down individual results.

What my (PHP)-script is like:

> Look in the MySQL-database if the query exists.
>
> **yes** => load the results from the database and show them to the user
>
> **no** => load the results from Faroo, show those results to the user and store them in the database

My database looks like this:

[image]

I'm getting all the data stored in the columns from the Faroo API, except for the 'id'-column.

The last part (of storing the Faroo-data in the database) is where it goes wrong:

```
for($x=0; $x<$tel; $x++){            
    $sql = "INSERT INTO queries (`id`, `query`, `title`, `url`, `domain`, `kwic`, `votes`) VALUES (NULL, $q, $titles[$x], $urls[$x], $domains[$x], $kwics[$x], 0);";
    echo '<br />'.$x.'e query: @'.$sql.'@';
    if(!$resultaat = $db->query($sql)){
        die('De query kon niet worden uitgevoerd: [' . $db->error . ']');
    }            
    $resultaat = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat);
}
```

`$tel` is a variable which counts the number of results I get from Faroo. It gets defined before this piece of code.
When I run this code, I am getting a nice MySQL-error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'States Bureau of Mines - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia,
> www.wikipedia.org' at line 1

I've searched, and searched, but I couldn't find what the SQL-error is. I think it has something to do with the strange characters in the strings, or maybe my quotation is false?

Kind regards,
Max

Comment: You need to quote your string values; or even better use [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728229/parameters-in-mysqli).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use single quotes `'` for varchar columns, so change as follow

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO queries (`id`, `query`, `title`, `url`, `domain`, `kwic`, `votes`) VALUES (NULL, '$q', '$titles[$x]', '$urls[$x]', '$domains[$x]', '$kwics[$x]', 0)";
```

You also have an extra double quote at the end of the query which i removed, you won't need singles quotes for columns `id` and `votes` since they are `integer` fields