# How to POST a newly defined variable into SQL - beginners PHP

Tags: php, sql, variables, post

The sql column avatar_link isn't updating:
A form submits data and directs to the script (partial) below. The SQL columns: name, comment, email and story_id all insert fine. The image saves to the server with no problem (I didn't include that part of the script to keep things brief). $templink is a newly created variable that should represent the URL of a image uploaded. I'm redefining the variable as $avatar_link and using POST.

```
    $tempLink = "http://www.website.com/avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $page_path = $_POST['page_path'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $storyid = $_POST['storyid'];
    $avatar_link = $_POST['$tempLink'];

    $con=mysqli_connect
    ("","","","");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO comments (name, comment, email, storyid, avatar_link, entry_date)';
    $sql .= 'VALUES("'.$name.'", "'.$comment.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$storyid.'", "'.$avatar_link.'", now())';
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
```

I marked the title of this 'beginners PHP' because this question seems very basic (and I can't still figure it out)...if that is not appropriate let me know and I will remove.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but surely `$avatar_link = $_POST['$tempLink'];` should just be `$avatar_link = $tempLink;`? It's not a POST parameter, it's just a variable defined in your PHP script.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Be more worried about that than not being able to do insert your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_POST variables come from a submitted form. If you are simply defining a variable and passing it into a statement for insertion into a database, you could eliminate a few steps here, and just do this:

```
$avatar_link = "http://www.website.com/avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Also, pay attention to @Marc B's comment here. You can learn about parameterizing mysqli statement all over the web, or [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728229/parameters-in-mysqli). What's really best, and what I'd recommend, is [learning PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338).

Comment: that did it. Also I'm posting a new question about security risks and their priority when designing a website. thank you all. great feedback here as always.