# Having ?postid = $value to view a certain MySQL Row

Tags: php, mysql, get

First of all, please excuse my noobish question. I'm building a blog platform and it all goes well, but I am totally unfamiliar with the $_GET method of PHP.

What I want to do is to have something like: when one goes to `http://link.dom/blog.php?postid = 1` for example, the page should `SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE id = 1`.

Please note I don't ask for any code, but about what I have to do to achieve what I want.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable value should be in `$_GET['postid']` on blog.php You should be able to use that item in the $_GET array in any way you desire. For instance, you could place it in a variable -

```
$postID = $_GET['postid']; // assigns the array value to a variable
```

Comment: So if I have for instance, more then one variable do I just separate them with `?` ?

Comment: No, the get separated with an ampersand `?foo=1&bar=2` and so on.

Comment: Hah, I expected something way more complex, thank you!

Comment: Highly dangerous. You're encouraging [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I'm not encouraging that @MarcB - I am just helping the OP to learn about query strings. But I'll edit and give a warning.

Comment: I'm filtering the $_GET data before actually running the query. Learned the injection lesson on myself.

Comment: Prepared statements are the way to go here! :-)

Comment: See here for how to use mysqli parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728229/parameters-in-mysqli  Putting "CAUTION" after an example of what NOT TO DO really doesn't help...

Comment: @ebyrob the question is not about SQL queries - the question is about query strings. the SQL query displayed was a response to the OP's example, showing how the query string **could** be used. Would I be better off eliminating the query from the answer?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Actually, if I may be so forward, yes.  I think removing it is better.  If you showed how to store the request variable into a PHP variable that would be a single, complete, and correct line of code.  It would also fully answer the question as asked.

Comment: @ebyrob Yeah, that makes sense to me too. Changes made.

Answer (score 3):

In Addition to Jay's Answer:

```
'SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE id = ' . (int)$_GET['postid'];
```

Note the `(int)`. It is casting the `postid` to an integer, to ensure, it is not an injection.

Depending on your Error Level you should prepend following:

```
if (!isset ($_GET['postid']) || !is_number($_GET['postid'])) {
    die('Error!');
}
```

Comment: This appeals to me.  I don't know enough PHP to know if it is really safe, but certainly the same concept in C# would be rock solid.