# How to fetch single row with PDO from href link, receives fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object?

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, pdo

I am starting to learn php PDO because I've read that it is more efficient and secure. 
I could do the following with simple mysqli but am having trouble making it work with PDO.

PID stands for an id number.
fname stands for: first name.
lname stands for: last name.
age stands for ... age.

Basically I have an index.php that contains links from a test table called "persons" inside of the database drinks. When I click on the link which shows the fname of every row, it goes to insertcarbonated.php which is then supposed to `$_GET['fname'];` of the link and search up that specific row. However, my code in insertcarbonated.php is not working and I am not familiar enough with PDO to know exactly why, I would like some enlightenment on this because I literally begun learning PDO yesterday. :(

Here is my insertcarbonated.php:

```
<html>
<?php 
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'theusername';

/*** mysql ***/
$password = 'thepass';

try {
     $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=drinks", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database';
    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/

    $fname = $_GET['fname'];
      //is _GET even working with PDO? 

    $STH = $dbh-> prepare( "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE fname LIKE '$fname'" );
     /***as Joachim suggested, I had actually two different variables here, however, it     
       did not solve the issue **EDITED** from ($DBH to $dbh)****/

    $STH -> execute();
    $result = $STH -> fetch(0);
     //$result should print out the first column correct? which is the person's ID. 

   }
catch(PDOException $e)
   {
   echo $e->getMessage();
   }



?>
<head>



</head>
<body>
 <p><?php print $result; ?></p>
 //me trying to print out person's ID number here. 

</body>



</html>
```

As previously mentioned, I'm not sure where my error is, I get fatal error:
**Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object?**

and If I try to not use that function, my page is simply blank and nothing prints out. 
Basically I would just like to print out different bits of information from that row (that is from it's relevant link in index.php). I would like to know how to solve this using PDO.

Here is the previous question I asked, and it was solved but not with PDO. 
[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225877/cant-output-relevant-mysql-information-to-clicked-link-using-select-from-table/24226323#24226323)

Comment: can you show us at which line the error happens?

Comment: @Bryan Based on the comments on the now deleted answer below, you need to update your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this...

```
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=drinks", $username, $password);

        $fname = $_GET['fname'];

        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE fname LIKE ?");
        $sth->execute( array($fname) );
        $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); // or try PDO::FETCH_ASSOC for an associative array
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       die( $e->getMessage() );
   }
```

In the HTML part you can do `print_r($result)` and you will see the exact structure of your results.

Comments: one of the best reasons to use PDO is the automatic escaping of the dynamic user inputs, like `$fname` here, so you should use it. Also, with `$sth->fetch($param)` the `$param` is not the column number but the type of the fetch method PDO will use (see [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)). Depending the method, you can get the PID of the result by `$result->PID` in case of `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` or by `$result['PID']` when using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. I hope this helps.

Comment: That query may return multiple rows so you'd want to use `fetch()` in a loop or use `fetchAll()`