# Php variables in for selecting in my mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, post

I try to make a selection in SQL using php variables. The code is like this:

```
$st=$_POST["st"] ;
$tu=$_POST["tu"] ; 
$data=$_POST["data"];
$ec= $_POST["ec"] ;

$sql="SELECT nr, '.$ec.' FROM 'report' WHERE st='.$st.' and tu='.$tu.' and dataupdate='.$data.'";
```

but I get 0 results.

If I change variables from the SQL query with values, it works. Also I test with

```
echo $st ; 
echo $tu ; 
echo $data ; 
echo $ec ;
```

and it returns correct value of post. Can anybody tell me what I do wrong ?

Comment: your sql is wrong. you can `echo` the `$sql` and try it on phpmyadmin to check weather its correct.

Comment: this error happened because you don't around your string variables with quotes. P.S. you can also use sprintf to avoid sql-injection. Or, better, use PDO

Answer (score 1):

Your right query

```
$sql="SELECT nr, '".$ec."' FROM 'report' WHERE st='".mysql_escape_string($st)."' and tu='".mysql_escape_string($tu)."' and dataupdate='".mysql_escape_string($data)."'";
```

Comment: I feel the Dark Side of the Force! I feel sql-injection here

Answer (score 1):

First, you're mixing string concatenation using `.` with replacing variable names directly inside a string quoted using `"`. You need to choose one of the approaches:

- `"SELECT '$ec' ..."`
- `"SELECT '" . $ec . "' ..."`

Second, your way to build the SQL query is **very** dangerous as it allows [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attack. Use parameterized queries instead: [parameters in MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728229/parameters-in-mysqli)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$st   = $_POST["st"];
$tu   = $_POST["tu"]; 
$data = $_POST["data"];
$ec   = $_POST["ec"];

$sql = "SELECT nr, $ec FROM `report` WHERE st='$st' and tu='$tu' and dataupdate='$data'";
```

Comment: what about some sql-injection in your query?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to overcome this.

Comment: I can, but instead I will use sprintf or PDO and prepare method :D