# use insert and select in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$new_id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc)    
foreach ($_POST['d_specialty'] as $key => $value) {
      $q = "INSERT INTO d_specialty (d_id, s_id) VALUES ($new_id, (SELECT specialty.id FROM specialty WHERE specialty.name = $value))";
      $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
```

i want to insert two values, the first one is a variable and the second is a select statement but the code above does not work...

Comment: The reason might be that your subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO d_specialty (d_id, s_id)
    SELECT $new_id, specialty.id
    FROM specialty
    WHERE specialty.name = $value;
```

Second, parameterize the query so `$new_id` and `$value` are passed in as parameters rather than put directly into the query string.  One reason is to prevent SQL injection attacks.  Another very important reason is to guard against potential syntax errors.

Comment: you mean create a function of the query and call it with the variables as a  parameters?

Comment: Aren't those variables already `parameterized`?

Comment: they are not @sgeddes

Comment: @OmarAlhadidy -- parameterized queries don't mean using a `function` and passing them...  With that said, I don't use `php` very often so I wasn't sure.  This looks right using `?` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728229/parameters-in-mysqli

Comment: thank you i will search a little bit more and correct them after that @sgeddes

Answer (score 1):

When using `insert into select` you don't need to use `values`.  Remove that and then move the `$new_id` variable into the `select` statement:

```
INSERT INTO d_specialty (d_id, s_id) 
SELECT $new_id, specialty.id 
FROM specialty 
WHERE specialty.name = $value
```