# MySQL subquery error: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

im trying to select all data from my "events" table whenever the "event id" matches with the "user id". However i get an error 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = (SELECT event_id FROM booking_dates WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}')";
$event_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

I understand that my subquery will return multiple rows because a user can attend multiple events. So how can I make my query accept multiple rows?

Comment: Could you show us the booking_dates and events structure, or atleast their associations (if any). You have to solve with with an INNER JOIN: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `in`:

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE id IN (SELECT event_id FROM booking_dates WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}')
```

Warning: injecting strings like that in your SQL makes them vulnerable to SQL injection. Please look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to which you can [bind arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) without this vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Others have shown how to correct your syntax. However, MySQL generally performs better if you use `JOIN` rather than `WHERE column IN (subquery)`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.*
FROM events AS e
JOIN booking_dates AS b ON e.id = b.event_id
WHERE b.user_id = '$user_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

You query should be using IN operator with where.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id IN (SELECT event_id FROM booking_dates WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}')";
$event_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SQL expert and as such my syntax may be a little off. However, I believe what you're looking for is an `IN` clause:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id IN (SELECT event_id FROM booking_dates WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}')";
$event_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

"So how can I make my query accept multiple rows?"

USE a Select that has a right join to the booking_dates table. The reason for the RIGHT JOIN is that you want to only display the records in the events table when there is 1 or more valid booking_dates records for the eventid and given user.
I believe to achieve multiple rows and only display the data the code will end up looking like this:

```
$query = "
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    events e
RIGHT JOIN
    booking_dates bd
    ON e.id=bd.event_id
WHERE 
    bd.user_id = '{$user_id}'";
$event_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

As recommended above it also best practice to make sure your SQL queries are "cleansed" using parameters and binding.
This stack overflow link provides the answer.
[parameters in MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728229/parameters-in-mysqli)