# Check if match the url parameter if correct and display the data

Tags: php, mysql

Im newbie in programmin
I want Check if the 2 parameter are correct and display the data

www.site.com/?param1=123&param2=444  <--- check if param1 and param2 are match and display the account.

On the database it has two same param2 and but different param1.

param1 | param2

123      444  First
122      444  Second

I want to display only the first

```php
$param1 = $_GET['param1'];
$param2 = $_GET['param2'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tests");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

}

}


if ( $param1 ==($param2)){

    echo "Display the data all the of first";

}

else{

    echo "incorrect parameter;";
}
```

Comment: you want to display only the first row from select query?

Comment: This is an example of how to deal with parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728229/parameters-in-mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysqli_fetch_all` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` in cycle: `$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`.

And then choose needed row to show (if it exists): `if (isset($rows[0])) { // your code to show }`.